# Error Installing Laravel: Mcrypt PHP extension required

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, mamp, mcrypt

I know there are a lot of questions about this on SO but none of them address my problem. I've checked everything they mention everything seems to indicate mcrypt is ok except when installing Laravel. Clearly I'm missing something.

When installing Laravel as directed (`composer create-project laravel/laravel myproj --prefer-dist`) I get the error "Mcrypt PHP extension required" at what seems to be near the end of installation.

As far as I can tell mcrypt **is** installed and enabled.

Composer uses `/usr/bin/env php`

```
$ which composer       
/usr/local/bin/composer

$ cat /usr/local/bin/composer
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/bin/env php -d allow_url_fopen=On -d detect_unicode=Off /usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.0.0-alpha8/libexec/composer.phar $*%
```

php on my PATH is 5.5.10 from MAMP

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.5.10 (cli) (built: Apr 10 2014 17:49:22)

$ which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/php
```

Mcrypt is installed and enabled

```
$ php -m | grep mcrypt
mcrypt

$ php --info | grep mcrypt                  
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value

$ php --ini                                 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

$grep mcrypt /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf/php.ini      
extension=mcrypt.so
```

I can see `mcrypt support` `enabled` in a phpinfo page via MAMP too.

What am I missing?

**edit:** I have `export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin:$PATH"` in `.bash_profile` and can confirm with `echo $PATH` and `which php`

**update:** a clue.

If I edit `/usr/local/bin/composer` to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $PATH
/usr/bin/env php --ini
```

and run `composer` I get

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Why is that PATH different?

Comment: Might be a long-shot but is the `mcrypt.so` file in the configured *extensions* directory?

Comment: Check http://laravel.io/forum/02-08-2014-difficulty-installing-laravel-getting-error-mcrypt-php-extension-required?page=1#reply-736. Composer may still be using the system PHP binary (due to `/usr/bin/env php`)

Comment: Yes and yes. I can see `mcrypt.so` in the dir that's specified in the ini and I have the MAMP php bin folder on my path (see edit)

Comment: Wait a sec... Everything above your edit uses `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10` yet your `PATH` contains `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19`. I'd say that's your problem. Upgraded MAMP recently?

Comment: Wait, are you running composer as root / via sudo? If so, don't do that

Comment: Thanks for all your help @phil. Sorry, the `5.4.19` is a typo. It's `5.5.10` really. And no, I'm not using sudo.

Comment: Better edit your question with the correct data then. Try running `source ~/.bash_profile && composer`. Perhaps your terminal session hasn't picked up the `PATH` changes

Comment: Nope :( same result. (I've been opening fresh terminal sessions anyway)

Comment: How did you install composer? It looks like it may have a sticky execute bit (SUID)

Comment: Installed with `brew`. Permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x` so no SUID, right?

Comment: I'm totally at a loss. This is why I use Vagrant on the mac

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230327/mcrypt-php-extension-required-in-laravel-with-ubuntu-14][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230327/mcrypt-php-extension-required-in-laravel-with-ubuntu-14

Answer (score 6):

**Getting Laravel working on Apache**

PHP version : PHP 5.5.9

Ubuntu version : 14.04

After a lot of trial and error and searching around , this is what i discovered . i had a working laravel project on windows, i copied it to ubuntu server and started getting the mcrypt error.

**getting artisan command working**

i did a lot of trial and error so each time i run the php5enmod command before, i had error messages. but on fresh install there was no error messages. after this step i got artisan command working

```
sudo rm /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
sudo apt-get purge php5-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

**fixing the browser error**

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

add the following line under the dynamically compiled extensions section of php ini

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

restart the apache server , purge the laravel cache and everything working

Comment: How does one "purge the laravel cache"?

Answer (score 1):

From what you've posted, it looks like composer is using a different PHP installation than your MAMP version.  One workaround would be using the PHAR version instead:

```
wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel myproj --prefer-dist
```

If your CLI php is registering mcrypt as an installed module, this will resolve your installation issue.

Comment: You'd think so, but even that doesn't work (same error).

Comment: @Jake - Do you have libmcrypt installed?  Have you verified that you're able to run the mcrypt functions via the CLI?

Comment: @SamDufel Good idea. Something like `php -r 'echo MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, PHP_EOL;'` should suffice (result should be `0`)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can find to make this work is to edit `/usr/local/bin/composer` and set the PATH in there like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin:$PATH"
/usr/bin/env php -d allow_url_fopen=On -d detect_unicode=Off /usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.0.0-alpha8/libexec/composer.phar $*
```

It's hacky and I'd still like to know what's up with my env but it works!

Answer (score 0):

i had also encounter similar problem, and following command worked for me.

`sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt`

Hope it will works your too.