# Mcrypt PHP extension required.IN Laravel With Ubuntu 14

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to migrate laravel app into ubuntu and getting error like **Mcrypt PHP extension required.**
when i check  php details with **phpinfo()** function it showing below screen.

[image: screen shot of mcrypt extension]

PLlease find the Terminal Screenshot below,

[image: terminal screenshot]

php.ini

[image]
How to solve this issue ?

Comment: This may helps you http://askubuntu.com/questions/507796/mcrypt-php-extension-required-laravel-xampp-error

Comment: Install `mcrypt` and Uncomment or add the `mcrypt` extension in `php.ini` file

Comment: Your php sapi may not be the same when serving scripts for your http server from when invoking in command line, so the php.ini file maybe a different one. Try php --ini in your bash to see which is the php.ini file for cli.

Comment: @demental, how can i solve this.

Comment: @demental,  Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini

Comment: So, is mcrypt.so enabled in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini  ?

Comment: @Demental, no. path is /opt/lampp/etc.

Comment: You can also double check typing  `php -i | grep mcrypt` and see fi you get mcrypt support => enabled in the output

Comment: @demental, how can i change the path to /opt/lampp/etc for php.ini .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69876/discussion-between-jishad-and-demental).

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed PHP through `apt-get` then find the mcrypt extension you are using either for apache by using

```
$ locate *mcrypt.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
/etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
/usr/share/php5/mcrypt/mcrypt.ini
/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:php5:mods-available:mcrypt.ini
```

go into the directory that you have your extension in

```
cd /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

and you will probably find there is a symlink to the mcrypt extension in the mods-available directory. If that's the case all you have to do is cd into the `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d` directory
and create a similar symlink

```
cd /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
sudo ln -s ../../mods-available/mcrypt.ini ./
```

then restart php maybe with `sudo service php5  restart`

That should work

Comment: getting error Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/timegear/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/timegear/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/timegear/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/timegear/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Comment: Unless any one else has any more ideas it sounds to me like Laravel is unable to read the Composer Autoload file. As you are getting permission denied I am guessing that you have run `composer update`.
I would run `sudo chmod 0755 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/timegear && chmod 0777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/timegear/app/storage`
if I have your file structure figured out correctly.
Again: other people may have other ideas.

Comment: when i run composer update terminal showing No command 'composer' found, did you mean:
 Command 'compose' from package 'mime-support' (main)
composer: command not found

Comment: Try installing Composer globally as described in [the Composer Getting started page](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: HI John, i tried the above command and showed it successfully installed.Then moved to the /usr/local/bin/composer directory. I am create d the composer directory before moving. and after i tried to run **composer** it will showing above mentioned error.

Comment: What do you get when you run `whereis composer` ?

Answer (score 0):

Find `mcrypt.ini` file in `/etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini` ,if this file does not exist,means php5-mcrypt could create the file.

- create the file `mcrypt.ini` in dir `/etc/php5/mods-available/`
- And add the following config to it:

  `extension=mcrypt.so`
- Run this commands

  `sudo php5enmod mcrypt`
    `sudo service php5-fpm restart`

This worked for me.Cheers