# laravel instal error with composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to instal laravel the following fairly sure I have mcrypt installed

```
me:~/public_html$ composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel-test
 Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.22)
 - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.22)
Loading from cache

Created project in laravel-test
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of      packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for laravel/framework v5.0.16 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.16].
- laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
```

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: @sameer-shaikh  using Ubuntu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Create an auxiliary symlink and enable the module:

```
cd /etc/php5/mods-available

ln -sf ../conf.d/mcrypt.ini .

php5enmod mcrypt
```

Finally, reload apache2 configuration:

```
service apache2 reload
```

Try this first and then run your above code as laravel needs mcrypt php extension installed.

Comment: I have done this, says it's already installed I also tried sudo apt-get --reinstall install php5-mcrypt

Comment: did you restart your terminal

Comment: Yes, I also added the line 'extension=mcrypt.so' to my php.ini file and it still makes no difference

Comment: Yes I have restarted apache

Comment: if I do 'sudo php5enmod mcrypt' returns 
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php5/mods-available

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
  sudo rm /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
  sudo apt-get purge php5-mcrypt
  sudo apt-get install mcrypt
  sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
  sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

link here - [Error Installing Laravel: Mcrypt PHP extension required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006701/error-installing-laravel-mcrypt-php-extension-required?rq=1)